# pandas drop_duplicates using comparison function

Tags: python, pandas

Is it somehow possible to use [pandas.drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with a comparison operator which compares two objects in a particular column in order to identify duplicates? If not, what is the alternative?

Here is an example where it could be used:

I have a pandas DataFrame which has lists as values in a particular column and I would like to have duplicates removed based on column `A`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'A': [[1,2],[2,3],[1,2]]} )
print df
```

giving me

```
        A
0  [1, 2]
1  [2, 3]
2  [1, 2]
```

Using [pandas.drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df.drop_duplicates( 'A' )
```

gives me a `TypeError`

```
[...]
TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not itertools.imap
```

However, my desired result is

```
        A
0  [1, 2]
1  [2, 3]
```

My comparison function would be here:

```
def cmp(x,y):
    return x==y
```

But in principle it could be something else, e.g.,

```
def cmp(x,y):
    return x==y and len(x)>1
```

How can I remove duplicates based on the comparison function in a efficient way?

Even more, what could I do if I had more columns to compare using a different comparison function, respectively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, your question is how to use an *arbitrary* function to determine what is a duplicate. To emphasize this, let's say that two lists are duplicates if the sum of the first item, plus the square of the second item, is the same in each case

```
In [59]: In [118]: df = pd.DataFrame( {'A': [[1,2],[4,1],[2,3]]} )
```

(Note that the first and second lists are equivalent, although not same.)

Python typically [prefers key functions to comparison functions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting), so here we need a function to say what is the key of a list; in this case, it is `lambda l: l[0] + l[1]**2`.

We can use [`groupby` + `first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) to group by the values of the key function, then take the first of each group:

```
In [119]: df.groupby(df.A.apply(lambda l: l[0] + l[1]**2)).first()
Out[119]: 
         A
A         
5   [1, 2]
11  [2, 3]
```

---

**Edit**

Following further edits in the question, here are a few more examples using

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'A': [[1,2],[2,3],[1,2], [1], [1], [2]]} )
```

Then for

```
def cmp(x,y):
    return x==y
```

this could be

```
In [158]: df.groupby(df.A.apply(tuple)).first()
Out[158]: 
             A
A             
(1,)       [1]
(1, 2)  [1, 2]
(2,)       [2]
(2, 3)  [2, 3]
```

for

```
def cmp(x,y):
     return x==y and len(x)>1
```

this could be

```
In [184]: class Key(object):
   .....:     def __init__(self):
   .....:         self._c = 0
   .....:     def __call__(self, l):
   .....:         if len(l) < 2:
   .....:             self._c += 1
   .....:             return self._c
   .....:         return tuple(l)
   .....:     

In [187]: df.groupby(df.A.apply(Key())).first()
Out[187]: 
             A
A             
1          [1]
2          [1]
3          [2]
(1, 2)  [1, 2]
(2, 3)  [2, 3]
```

Alternatively, this could also be done much more succinctly via

```
In [190]: df.groupby(df.A.apply(lambda l: np.random.rand() if len(l) < 2 else tuple(l))).first()
Out[190]: 
                     A
A                     
0.112012068449     [2]
0.822889598152     [1]
0.842630848774     [1]
(1, 2)          [1, 2]
(2, 3)          [2, 3]
```

but some people don't like these Monte-Carlo things.

Comment: Need to be careful with that `df.A.apply(sum)` - throw a `[0, 3]` and a `[10, -5]` in there and you're going to get confused...

Comment: @JonClements Not sure I see your point. I tried to show in the answer how to use an arbitrary function for equivalence, using list sum as an example. IIUC, you're suggesting adding to equivalent elements (using this criteria) to those already there, and, indeed, they are removed.

Comment: Ahhh right... while I appreciate it's an example and it's probably just me - but I just think using `sum` is a rather misleading example as `[0, 3]` is not intuitively a duplicate of `[1, 2]` (going by the OPs data)... But re-reading it, yes, I see your point that you're demonstrating groupby/first - I just personally feel that either `tuple` or `frozenset` might be a better choice in this case...

Comment: ... both of course have caveats... a `tuple` won't catch your `[1,2]` and `[2, 1]` but a `frozenset` will, but that'd also catch `[1, 1, 2]` and `[2, 1]` - so I'd probably take a stab that `df.groupby(df.A.apply(sorted).apply(tuple), as_index=False).first()` is a reasonable candidate...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for these valuable points - appreciated! I'll find a better example (that doesn't have a simpler / more efficient alternative.

Comment: That is a nice solution if I can define a key function which basically maps a value to each object in the column and the comparison is done on this key value. But I'm interested in a more general solution. I have updated my question and gave an alternative comparison function which I would like to use.

Comment: @desiato The [Python sorting docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) discuss key functions a bit. See update.

Comment: Interesting. So in general I've to translate my comparison function which takes two objects and returns True if the objects are similar otherwise False into a key function which takes one object and returns an object, i.e., integer or tuple or something else on which a comparison can be done internally.

Comment: @desiato Using this approach, yes. Key functions are used in current Python for sorting, grouping, etc. The standard docs explain how key functions are a generalization of comparison functions, and a lot is known about this. This is a very general technique. Having said that, note that for certain things in Pandas, while this technique will work, there are shorter and/or more efficient approaches.

Answer (score 4):

***Option 1***

```
df[~pd.DataFrame(df.A.values.tolist()).duplicated()]
```

[image]

***Option 2***

```
df[~df.A.apply(pd.Series).duplicated()]
```

Comment: This is very efficient and clear for the case the OP is asking.

Comment: This is a nice solution for the example gave. But I'm looking for something more general using an abitrary function for the identification of duplicates in a column.

Answer (score 3):

`Lists` are unhashable in nature. Try converting them to hashable types such as `tuples` and then you can continue to use `drop_duplicates`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].map(tuple)
df.drop_duplicates('A').applymap(list)
```

[image]

---

One way of implementing it using a function would be based on computing `value_counts` of the series object, as duplicated values get aggregated and we are interested in only the `index` part (which by the way is unique) and not the actual count part.

```
def series_dups(col_name):
    ser = df[col_name].map(tuple).value_counts(sort=False)
    return (pd.Series(data=ser.index.values, name=col_name)).map(list)

series_dups('A')

0    [1, 2]
1    [2, 3]
Name: A, dtype: object
```

---

If you do not want to convert the values to `tuple` but rather process the values as they are, you could do:

**Toy data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1,2], [2,3], [1,2], [3,4]], 
                   'B': [[10,11,12], [11,12], [11,12,13], [10,11,12]]})
df
```

[image]

```
def series_dups_hashable(frame, col_names):
    for col in col_names:
        ser, indx = np.unique(frame[col].values, return_index=True)
        frame[col] = pd.Series(data=ser, index=indx, name=col)
    return frame.dropna(how='all')

series_dups_hashable(df, ['A', 'B'])   # Apply to subset/all columns you want to check
```

[image]

Comment: This is very efficient and clear for the case the OP is asking.

Comment: This is a nice solution for the example I gave. But I'm looking for something more general using an abitrary function for the identification of duplicates in a column.

Comment: @desiato: See if (*my edited response*) answers your purpose.

Comment: You assume that I can convert the objects in the column into a hashable object, respectively. Is there a possibility without this assumption?

Comment: @desiato: Yup.. I just figured it out now. (*See edit*)